# Switching databases between development and deployment

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

Hy guys,
how to switch probably databases from development to deployment in **yii2-advanced**!
I use following config-file:

```
.
.
.
     'db_developpment' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2_widget',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'db_deployment' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host="http:/tklustig.ddns.net";dbname=yii2_widget',
            'username' => 'my_name',
            'password' => 'my_password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
.
.
.
```

I suppose, it's necessary to code an IF-statement in order to difference between developpment and deployment settings.
How to code this IF-statement correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need two DB connections at the same time? It makes everything more complicated.

The preferred way is to keep several environments configuration. Each environment uses it's own DB connection setup.

See the [Yii 2 Advanced Template Project](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-environments.md) docs about this.

Basically you prepare two different configs:

- `/environments/dev/common/config/main-local.php`
- `/environments/prod/common/config/main-local.php`

Inside there is `db` component configured for each environment. When deploying app you run console command `init` where you choose environment to be initialized so the proper `main-local.php` file is copied to folder and now `db` component uses the environment-based configuration so you just use **one** active connection.